# Can't get ${server.port} from application.yml in @SpringApplicationConfiguration annotated test

Tags: testing, spring-boot

I get a `-1` value returned when trying to get the `server.port` property from `application.yml` in a test context.

I do black box testing of a Spring-bot app.
Here's a test case:

```java
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(TestConfiguration.class)
public class StartupTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests implements EnvironmentAware {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StartupTest.class);

    @Value("${server.port}")
    private String port;

    @Value("${project.name}")
    private String name;

    private RelaxedPropertyResolver propertyResolver;

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.propertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment);
    }

    @Test
    public void isAppUpAndRunning() {
        logger.debug("port: " + port);
        logger.debug("name: " + name);
        logger.debug("value for project.name: " + propertyResolver.getProperty("project.name"));
        logger.debug("value for server.port: " + propertyResolver.getProperty("server.port"));
        logger.debug("value for server.servlet-path: " + propertyResolver.getProperty("server.servlet-path"));
    }
}
```

NB: `TestConfiguration.class` contains nothing but `@Configuration`

Output:

```java
[DEBUG] com.project.StartupTest - Running with Spring Boot v1.3.3.RELEASE, Spring v4.2.5.RELEASE
[INFO] com.project.StartupTest - The following profiles are active: test
[INFO] com.project.StartupTest - Started StartupTest in 4.698 seconds (JVM running for 7.761)
[DEBUG] com.project.StartupTest - port: ${server.port}
[DEBUG] com.project.StartupTest - name: ${project.name}
[DEBUG] com.project.StartupTest - value for project.name: MyProject
[DEBUG] com.project.StartupTest - value for server.port: -1
[DEBUG] com.project.StartupTest - value for server.servlet-path: /
```

So there's actually 2 questions here:

- why can't I get the properties injected with the `@Value` annotation?
- why can I get all `application.yml` properties with a `PropertyResolver` but `server.port` ?

What I need ultimately is a convenient way to access all the `application.yml` properties in a 'classic' test (i.e. not a Spring integration test as I want to test the application as it is at runtime). I've tried using

```java
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class, initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
```

as well, but the problem remains the same.

Comment: You haven't told the testing infrastructure that you're running a web-based test. Try annotating your test class with `@WebIntegrationTest`

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to use `@WebIntegrationTest` because I don't need to start an embedded container, I don't want to start the application: I just need to run a Spring's RestTemplate to black box test my Rest layer. But I need to have access to the `application.xml` and the Spring profiles for this. And I do have access to all properties, all be it not with the convenient `@Value` annotation, but `server.port` or `local.server.port`. `management.port` for instance IS available.

Comment: If you want to black-box test using RestTemplate you will need spring boot to start up a Web server (otherwise what are you going to fire your requests at) and the spring-boot way to do this is using @WebIntegrationTest. If you just want to test your controller then the mvc test classes can do that by mocking the Dispatcher

Comment: The web server is fired at Maven's integration-test phase, then I can run as many integration test as I want without having to restart a web server each time. This work very well, and is a clean way to separate "application" testing (including Unit test & Spring's WebIntegrationTest) and black box testing against a running server. These are all perfectly compatible and complementary.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not running an integration test, [`SpringApplicationContextLoader` explicitly sets `server.port` to `-1`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/test/SpringApplicationContextLoader.java#L147). A value of `-1` disables the embedded servlet container, which is what you have asked for by not using `@WebIntegrationTest`.

Comment: Right, that explains. I think my use case is a valid one though: I run black-box integration test during the Maven's `integration-test` phase which startup the spring-boot app with a chosen profile and let's me run as many test as I want without having to restart a web server for each of them. 
It's a complementary approach for me, I use Spring's WebIntegrationTest during unit testing AND black-box/integration test. This is perfectly fine and run all very well together.

Comment: It's only that I need to have access to the `application.yml` properties at test runtime, which I do thanks to `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` but then can't get the only property that apparently has a special status, and a very important one: `server.port`

Do you feel it's a legitimate feature I could request?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Note that `application.yml` isn't the only source of a property's value. You _are_ getting the value of `server.port`, it's just that it's been set to `-1` as you have told the test infrastructure that you do not want the embedded container to be started. That setting take precedences over whatever is in `application.yml` otherwise the embedded container would be started even though your test configuration is such that it should not be.

Comment: I mean there could be another way to avoid the startup of the embedded container. The choice of using this existing property `server.port` and to give it a special value for this purpose kind of breaks the property usage pattern. My use case which I believe is not an unusual one, using maven integration-test phase to startup the container, has to rely on the `server.port` property to know on which port the container is listening. Why not use a dedicated property for this, like `start.container` ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the `@Value` annotation in the integration test were not filling the properties with values (instead the placeholder ${..} was in there).

I 'solved' it for now by adding the `PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.class` to the `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`, ie:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(TestConfiguration.class, PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.class)
```

However I'm not very happy with this so I opened a question on how to do this properly:
[Spring boot integration test with SpringApplicationConfiguration doesn't seem to resolve @Value annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38075878/spring-boot-integration-test-with-springapplicationconfiguration-doesnt-seem-to)

Answer (score 0):

In test cases the running server's port is available in the `local.server.port` property:

```
@Value("${local.server.port}")
private int localServerPort;
```

Comment: Injecting properties with `@Value` is not working as I mentioned in the post. Besides `local.server.port` is not available either with a `PropertyResolver`.